# Omni-channel is enabled but not shown in "Choose Console Components"

Tags: omnichannel

I'm facing a strange issue. I'm trying to enable sales console in my partial sandbox org. I did read and walk through salesforce guides did enable omnichannel in omni-channel settings:

[image: Omni-channel settings]

But when I go to console app and go down to "Choose Console Components", there's no "omni-channel" component to add.

[image: No omnichannel component]

I also did try to read and do through guides by salesforce devs/cons (i.e. [Guha Anandh](https://guhasdevforce.wordpress.com/2016/05/25/omni-channel-setup/)) yet unsuccessfull.

I did try to do the same on my home dev org and everything worked, the component appears in the list.
Please, help me. What could be the issue? Where to dig, how to debug this strange behaviour? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ran into this same issue and finally came to the resolution.

Ensure that you have Service Cloud Licenses available and they are enabled (check box marked) for each of your required users.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=console2_assign_service_feature_license.htm&type=0

Once you have done this the Omni-Channel item should should in the "Choose Console components" section.